# SOAP WebService response structure recommended

Tags: web-services, soap, data-structures, xsd, standards

I'm developing a SOAP WebService (designed to be Document Literal Wrapped). Sinking in web, I'm seeing some methods that have as response the following structure: complex type named [*function_name + "Response"*] followed by complex type [*function_name + "Result"*]

Is there any reason (standard reason or good practice) why is done in that way? (Specially the "Result" complex type).

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice. Since soap is of XML type, how will you differentiate between request xml and response xml?
It helps the developer to write the code based on request/response.
Example: marshaling and unmarshaling.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the difference and the needs between Request and Response complex types, but the "Result" type could be unnecesary?
[https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-best9/index.html](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-best9/index.html)